# Load paypal website within my website

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to load PayPal website within my website? It is a requirement of client. Since PayPal is click jacking protected,  tag will not work in this case. Is there another way to perform this task ?

Comment: Have you tried using an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be able to do that with PayPal's [Direct Integration](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Merchant/bizui/IntegrationDirect-outside) feature?

[PayPal Link](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Merchant/bizui/IntegrationDirect-outside)

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of this feature. I will try this for sure.